# React Component State Being Reset to Default

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

I am trying to track a form in `this.state` with event handlers on the inputs, but for some reason `this.state` is being reset back to its default state when the event handler tries to update it. This is an example of what the Component looks like.

```
class ExampleReport extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            reportDetails: null,
            report: this.props.report,
            form: {}
        }
        this.textInputHandler = this.textInputHandler.bind(this)
    }

    textInputHandler(e) {
        var reportForm = this.state.form;
        var target = e.target;
        var name = target.className;
        var value = target.value;
        reportForm[name] = value;
        this.setState({ form: reportForm })
    }

    render(){
      return(
        <form>
          <input className="example" type="text" onChange={(e) => {this.textInputHandler(e)}} />
        </form>
      )
    }
}
```

Before `textInputHandler` is called, `this.state` has an object and array stored in it, but once `setState` is called they are reset back to the default in the constructor. On subsequent updates to the text input `this.state.form` persists but everything else is reset. How can I prevent this from happening?

**UPDATE**

After trying some of the solutions suggested below I went back and logged `this.state` at just about every possible point and found that it is reset even before `setState()` is being called in the input handler.

Comment: remove `<form>` from your return in `render` function.
Or put `e.preventDefault` in your input handler.

Comment: Once way to solve this would be `this.setState({ form: { ...reportForm} })`  without making further modifications but use the answer provided by @Kirill below

Comment: @UtsavPatel I tried both of your suggestions, but neither seemed to work

Answer (score 0):

You forget about input value and update state by ref (make mutation).

```js
class ExampleReport extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            reportDetails: null,
            report: this.props.report,
            form: { example: '', },
        }

        this.textInputHandler = this.textInputHandler.bind(this)
    }

    textInputHandler(e) {
        const { target: { name, value } } = e;

        this.setState(prevState => ({
          ...prevState,
          form: {
            ...prevState.form,
            [name]: value,
          },
        }));
    }

    render() {
      const { form: { example } } = this.state;

      return (
        <form>
          <input
            className="example"
            type="text"
            name="example"
            value={example}
            onChange={this.textInputHandler}
          />
        </form>
      )
    }
}
```

Comment: `...prevState,` is not needed in OP's case, Inside `form` spreading `...prevState.form` seems right solution

Comment: I tried out this solution, but still see the same problem. See the update to the post, the problem may not be with `setState`

Comment: well, I've created a project on [codeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-pond-1itlk).

Answer (score 0):

Once way to solve this would be like below, spreading reportForm in a new object

```
  textInputHandler(e) {
        var reportForm = this.state.form;
        var target = e.target;
        var name = target.className;
        var value = target.value;
        reportForm[name] = value;
        this.setState({ form: { ...reportForm } }) // <----------------------
    }
```

However you may want to use more declarative solution as provided by Kirill but without unnecessary state changes

```
  textInputHandler(e) {
        const { className: name, value } = e.target;
        this.setState(prevState => { form: { ...prevState.form, [name]: value } }) // <----------------------
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try changing your onChange to this

```
onChange={this.textInputHandler}
```

like how they have it in the react documentation
EX)

```
<input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
```

then do the spreading stuff 
don't add, e.preventDefault because that only works for submitting

Look at Krill answer he has everything you need on there
compare it to yours from the top, you have a lot of stuff missing